# Azure load balance traffic distribution

Tags: server, azure-web-app-service, windows-server-2016, azure-load-balancer

I have 2 VMs with Windows server 2016 on Azure. I want to the setup load balancer in front of both VMs so that every request to the VMs coming through the load balancer and load balancer distribute it to healthy backend instances.

My question is that what is the default behaviour of traffic distribution in Azure LB.
How can we distribute traffic in the **round robin**?

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

Default is round robin. the only quirk is that you setup probes for this to work, and if probe detect failure LB wont distribute traffic to failed host(S).